# find weight matrix for Temporal Associative Memories

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am finding weight matrix for Temporal Associative Memories my vectors are

```
x1 = [ 1 –1 1 –1 1 –1 1 –1 ]
x2 = [ 1 1 –1 –1 1 1 –1 –1 ]
x3 = [ 1 1 1 1 –1 –1 –1 –1 ]
```

and equation to find weight matrix is `W = T(X1)*X2 + T(X2)*X3 + T(X3)*X1` where `T` is transpose

```
x1 = [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1]
x2 = [1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
x3 = [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
x = pd.DataFrame(data=[x1, x2, x3]).T

w = np.zeros(np.max(x.shape), np.max(x.shape))
for n in range(x.shape[0] - 1):
    w1 = np.dot(x[n], x[n + 1])
    w += w1
    w += np.dot([-1], [1])
print(w)
```

[image: my answer should be this]

Comment: Is there a reason for `pandas.DataFrame` here? Why not just a plain `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: it is for the further process not really important right now to

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are brackets missing in initialization of `w`, it should be `w = np.zeros((np.max(x.shape), np.max(x.shape)))` to get proper shape.

Second, you want to iterate over columns of dataframe, so you need to use

```
for n in range(x.shape[1]):
```

Note that this will give you `n` values `[0,1,2]` not `[1,2,3]` (as in the book you're referring to), but this is ok since column names in pandas are by default numbered from zero as well.

In the last iteration this will give you n+1=3 and you want to address first column (indexed with 0) instead. This can be corrected with if statement.

When it comes to vector multiplication - np.dot, which you are using, performs inner product. It will treat the first vector as horizontal and second as vertical and then perform matrix multiplication. Instead, you should use np.outer, to get reversed alignment of vectors.

Last thing - I do not know what the last line inside the loop is doing
`w += np.dot([-1], [1])`
this does not seem to be needed (based on the book you're referring to)

Putting this all together gives following code:

```
x1 = [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1]
x2 = [1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
x3 = [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
x = pd.DataFrame(data=[x1, x2, x3]).T

w = np.zeros((np.max(x.shape), np.max(x.shape)))

for n in range(x.shape[1]):
    next_idx = n+1
    if next_idx == x.shape[1]:
        next_idx = 0
    w1 = np.outer(x[n], x[next_idx])  
    w += w1

print(w)
```

Comment: Thank you, That was really helpful